# hiding .env file within a project

Tags: node.js, git, react-fullstack

This is my file directory structure

project

- client
- server (has the .env file with credentials)

How can I hide credentials in the .env file when I push to github? I know that you have to use .gitignore but how would that work since my .env is not in the root directory?

**UPDATE**

I tried doing what the response said but the .env file still did not disappear in my repo.

[image: Root]
[image: Server folder]

Here is what the .gitignore file reads:

```
.env
.idea
**/node_modules
data
yarn.lock
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add `.env` to `.gitignore`, then `git add .gitignore` followed by `git commit`. This will ignore `.env` in all subdirectories from future git operations, so the `.env` file will not be pushed at all to GitHub.

The [`.gitignore` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) specifies *patterns* of a file or directory name, not the explicit path relative to the location of `.gitignore` in the directory tree. This means that you don't need to specify `project/client/.env` etc separately.

So, just add this to your `.gitignore`:

```
.env
```

If you already accidentally pushed your `.env` file and it contained sensitive credentials, revoke those credentials immediately and treat them as if bots have already scraped them, and follow the instructions here: [Removing sensitive data from a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository)

As a side-note, if your application requires environmental variables to work, it's customary to document them in your README. I also often see a file named like `.env.sample` or something similar, which is a boilerplate for each developer's own `.env` file. This file usually just contains the keys without the values, so other developers know which variables they need to set up.

Comment: I edited my post because it did not work for me. Hopefully you can help? Thank you so much for your support

Comment: Since you've already committed the `.env` file, do `git rm ./**/.env` followed by `git commit`, then follow the steps here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository